# Type-safe mixin decorator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator, mixins

I tried to define type-safe `mixin()` decorator function like follows,

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function mixin<T>(MixIn: Constructor<T>) {
    return function decorator<U>(Base: Constructor<U>) : Constructor<T & U> {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MixIn.prototype).forEach(name => {
            Base.prototype[name] = MixIn.prototype[name];
        });

        return Base as Constructor<T & U>;
    }
}
```

And used it as follows,

```
class MixInClass {
    mixinMethod() {console.log('mixin method is called')}
}

/**
 *  apply mixin(MixInClass) implicitly (use decorator syntax)
 */
@mixin(MixInClass)
class Base1 {
    baseMethod1() { }
}
const m1 = new Base1();
m1.baseMethod1();
m1.mixinMethod(); // error TS2339: Property 'mixinMethod' does not exist on type 'Base1'.
```

Then, compiler said `m1` didn't have the member `'mixinMethod'`.

And generated code is as follows,

```
//...
var Base1 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Base1() {
    }
    Base1.prototype.baseMethod1 = function () { };
    Base1 = __decorate([
        mixin(MixInClass)
    ], Base1);
    return Base1;
}());
//...
```

It looks that `mixin` decorator was applied correctly.

So, in my understanding, the type of `m1` is inferred as `Base1 & MixIn`. But compiler says it's just `Base1`.

I used `tsc 2.6.2` and compiled these codes with `--experimentalDecorators` flag.

Why does compiler fail to recognize the type as I expected?

---

Based on @jcalz's answer, I modified my code as follows,

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T

function mixin<T1, T2>(MixIns:  [Constructor<T1>, Constructor<T2>]): Constructor<T1&T2>;
function mixin(MixIns) {
    class Class{ };

    for (const MixIn of MixIns) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MixIn.prototype).forEach(name => {
            Class.prototype[name] = MixIn.prototype[name];
        });
    }

    return Class;
}

class MixInClass1 {
    mixinMethod1() {}
}

class MixInClass2 {
    mixinMethod2() {}
}

class Base extends mixin([MixInClass1, MixInClass2]) {
    baseMethod() { }
}

const x = new Base();

x.baseMethod(); // OK
x.mixinMethod1(); // OK
x.mixinMethod2(); // OK
x.mixinMethod3(); // Property 'mixinMethod3' does not exist on type 'Base' (Expected behavior, Type check works correctly)
```

This works pretty well. I want to improve this `mixin` function for variable length mixin classes.

One solution is adding overload function declaration like follows,

```
function mixin<T1>(MixIns: [Constructor<T1>]): Constructor<T1>;
function mixin<T1, T2>(MixIns: [Constructor<T1>, Constructor<T2>]): Constructor<T1&T2>;
function mixin<T1, T2, T3>(MixIns: [Constructor<T1>, Constructor<T2>, Constructor<T3>]): Constructor<T1&T2&T3>;
```

But this is too ugly. Are there any good ideas? Is it impossible until [variadic-kind](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) is supported?

Comment: +1 for the aesthetics of this solution without the nested class. I've looked around, seems like the only solution for now is like you said. I'd wondered if maybe there was some kind of ts preprocessor that could dynamically generate the above overloads to make the workaround more bearable to no avail. For now I just made a noddy little util that generated the markup for n overloads in a way where TS wouldnt complain about formatting. Looking forward to a proper solution. Great work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decorators don't mutate the type signature of the decorated class the way you're expecting.  There's a [rather lengthy issue in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) which discusses this, and it's not clear there's agreement on how (or if) such mutation should be implemented.  The main problem right now is that the compiler understands `Base1` as the undecorated class, and doesn't have a name for the decorated version.

From reading that Github issue, it looks like the suggested workaround (for now at least) is something like:

```
class Base1 extends mixin(MixInClass)(
  class {
    baseMethod1() { }
  }) {
}
```

So you're not using the decorator `@` notation, and instead directly applying the decorator function to an anonymous class (which has the same implementation of your desired `Base1`), and then subclassing *that* to get `Base1`.  Now the compiler understands that `Base1` has both a `baseMethod1()` and a `mixinMethod()`.

Hope you find that helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for describing. I understood it!