# Typescript incompatible type error, but type is correct. Only happens with method decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to use a method decorator to coerce the type of an argument to a method. It seems like it should work. And the JS output runs correctly. Here is my code:

```js
interface FooLike {
    a: number
}

function coerceToFoo(target: Foo, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(f: Foo | FooLike) {
        return method.call(this, (f instanceof Foo) ? f : new Foo(f));
    }
    return descriptor;
}


class Foo {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    constructor({a = 1, b = 2}={}) {
        Object.assign(this, {a, b});
    }

    @coerceToFoo
    bar(f: Foo) {
        return f.a + f.b;
    }
}

const f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar({a: 6}));
```

When I compile it I get:

```
$ tsc
foo.ts:28:19 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.
  Type '{ a: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Foo': b, bar

28 console.log(f.bar({a: 6}));
                     ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

When I run the built output, it works as expected.

```
$ node build/foo.js
8
```

Comment: This is the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372465/type-safe-mixin-decorator-in-typescript); for better or worse, TypeScript doesn't allow decorators to mutate the type of the decorated class, see [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881).  The type signature of the `bar()` method is therefore not mutated.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of the other question.  If you think that the answer there does not apply here, please elaborate on the difference.  Cheers!

Comment: Maybe the difference is that you're decorating a property instead of a class, so the workaround solution isn't helpful unless you write your own `applyPropertyDecorator` function.  It's blecch though.  I don't know if there's a answer that doesn't just have you manually fix the types with assertions or declaration merging